# How to run a setTimeout after my page loads?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, timeout, settimeout

I want to run a time out function to show an image once the page is loaded but I don't know why it's not running. Is this a matter of syntax?
Here's my code:

```
const screenshot = document.querySelector('#device-screenshot'); 
function loaded() {
console.log('loaded')
setTimeout(() => {screenshot.src = "dist/images/new-screenshot-2.jpeg"
  }, 4000); 
}

if (screenshot.complete) {
loaded()
} else {
screenshot.addEventListener('load', loaded)
screenshot.addEventListener('error', function() {
console.log('error')
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall correctly, you don't need the curly braces in the `setTimeout()` function. Normal syntax could be as follows:

```js
function loaded() {
    console.log('loaded')
    setTimeout(() => screenshot.src = "dist/images/new-screenshot-2.jpeg", 4000); 
}
```

If this doesn't work, then check to see if there is another way than `.complete` to check if it is loaded. I have never seen nor used it, but this looks like correct usage and the `loaded()` function should fire when the page loads. Alternatively, you can hook up an `onload` attribute to the `body` tag in the HTML file and set the value to `'loaded'` or another function instead of waiting for the image to load.

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem. Just solved it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `onload` event, you would use it like so:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", loaded);
```